# How to add font awesome icon to the left of a rails link_to helper in haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, font-awesome

```
= link_to "PREVIOUS", display_featured_path(:current_featured_statement_id => statement.id, :direction => "previous"), :remote => true, :class=> ""
```

This is my code, but I want to add an arrow that points left, to the left of the 'Previous' link. I've been playing with it for a while, but haven't found a solid solution.

Any help, much appreciated.

I've tried Ronaks solutions, but i'm getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
= link_to display_featured_path(current_featured_statement_id: statement.id, direction: "previous"), remote: true do 
  i.fa.fa-calculator
    Previous
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working. results in a syntax error.

Comment: This answer was very helpful. I was able to get it to work for my use case. The only thing I would is that I didn't need the single quotes around the word Previous. In other words, the single quotes get rendered on the page, so you probably want to leave them out. What exactly was the syntax error?